# Flutter: problems with Android app after installation

Tags: android, flutter

This is not a duplicate of the question: [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

The problem is when running an app on independent device, not connected to the computer.

Basically, I have a Flutter app that works fine in Run mode and Hot Reload of Android Studio and on the connected device.

However, when I created .apk file, placed this file to the Google Play Market and downloaded the app into the smartphone, the app does not work.

It looks like this: I press "Open" on the icon of the mobile app, I see a message "App has stopped" with available options "Open app again" and "Send feedback".

My questions are:

(1) How is it possible to check what exact failure the app has?

(2) Is it possible to use Fabric for Flutter apps? If yes - does this require the same actions as for an Android mobile app?

Thank you in advance for your support.

Sincerely,
Mary

Comment: (1) with a debugger (2) yes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: I have edited the question, it is not a duplicate since  in a moment of crash, the smartphone is not connected to the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics

**Firebase crashlytics:**
Whenever your app crashes or throws an error, the firebase crashlytics library will capture it and sends the details to firebase.
Make an account on firebase, and create an app. Click on Crashlytics on the side menu and complete the setup. It should start logging crashes to your firebase account.

**Background:**
I am getting the same issue. It works on many phones. But some of my users keep getting the error "Unfortunately myApp has stopped working". I just connected it to firebase_crashlytics. This works very well in Native Android apps. I am trying for the first time in Flutter.